# How do mySQL arrange primary keys in SHOW CREATE TABLE?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I created a table, here is what SHOW CREATE TABLE did:

```
CREATE TABLE  `x` (
  `COMPETITION_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PLAYER1A_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PLAYER1B_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PLAYER2A_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PLAYER2B_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SCORE` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DATEAT` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `REPLAY_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ONTREE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PLAYER1A_ID`,`PLAYER1B_ID`,`PLAYER2A_ID`,`PLAYER2B_ID`,`COMPETITION_ID`,`ONTREE`),
  KEY `FK__2v2_ladder_3` (`PLAYER1B_ID`),
  KEY `FK__2v2_ladder_4` (`PLAYER2A_ID`),
  KEY `FK__2v2_ladder_5` (`PLAYER2B_ID`),
  KEY `FK__2v2_ladder_6` (`REPLAY_ID`),
  KEY `FK__2v2_ladder_1` (`COMPETITION_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK__2v2_ladder_1` FOREIGN KEY (`COMPETITION_ID`) REFERENCES `competitions` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK__2v2_ladder_2` FOREIGN KEY (`PLAYER1A_ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK__2v2_ladder_3` FOREIGN KEY (`PLAYER1B_ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK__2v2_ladder_4` FOREIGN KEY (`PLAYER2A_ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK__2v2_ladder_5` FOREIGN KEY (`PLAYER2B_ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK__2v2_ladder_6` FOREIGN KEY (`REPLAY_ID`) REFERENCES `uploads` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;
```

if you check the `PRIMARY KEY` part, you can pick up that the order is not the column order - it should be COMPETITION_ID, PLAYER1A_ID, PLAYER1B_ID, PLAYER2A_ID, PLAYER2B_ID, ONTREE. How did the MySQL make that arrange? Does it count at all?

Comment: What GUI are you using?

Comment: Columns order in the database doesn't matter, but order in the index does matter a lot. It is not mysql that defined this index, someone had to do it.

Comment: Im using MySQL Query Browser. So youre saying it set the order (wrongly) and not the MySQL itself?

Comment: In other words, it doesnt matter if I set PRIMARY KEY (a, b, c) and PRIMARY KEY (b, c, a) ?

Comment: These two are different, for example if you want to `order by a` the index on (a,b,c) would help with that but the other one would not.

Comment: I see. Please make it as a post so that I can accept it